# AngularJS Material md-tab scrolling not working

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

I'm new to AngularJS Material and am trying to get a mdDialog to work, but am running into a weird issue with md-tabs.  My labels are pretty long and the scrolling/pagination doesn't work.  If I change my md-tab label to something short like label="Part {{$index + 1}}", it works great.

What do I need to change in order for the tab scrolling to work

```
<md-dialog-content>
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="tabIndex">
    <md-tab ng-repeat="x in data.sections track by $index"  label="{{x.section_name}}">
        <!-- content goes here --->
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
</md-dialog-content>
```

Below is a snapshot of what my dialog box looks like.  Both scrolling arrows are disabled for some reason and I can't figure out how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a quick plunker with just the tabs to demonstrate this?

Comment: Hi Vijay, I will try to make one this weekend, thanks!  Just to provide some more context, when I make the label longer -- label="{{$index + 1}}. {{x.section_name}}", the next and previous buttons become active and work great...something must be weird with the dialog box not recognizing the width of the last, partially hidden tab.  Although I've found a work around (totally not ideal), I would still like a more elegant solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Please check this link as well. There is an issue in the github link:https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5794     Thats why just wanted to check your code .

Comment: @VijayMenon, nice, that fixed it! thanks!

Comment: @Dave how u fixed. Can u please elaborate